# PL/SQL - How to return single row from a joined table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

this might be quite simple I'm just not seeing the wood for the trees at the moment. In Oracle I'm selecting records from table A that joins to table B based on the primary key of table A. However table B can have multiple records matching the primary key of table A. This is causing my query to return duplicate rows from table A. Below is a cut down version of my query:

```
TableA                TableB
_______               _________
1, Sec1                2, 11/01/2011
2, Sec2                2
3, Sec3                5, 10/01/2011
4, Sec4                6, 10/01/2011

Select A.SecID, A.SecName, B.DateSent from tableA A   
  inner join tableB B on A.SecID = B.SecID
```

This is returning 2 records for Sec2 - how can I get it to return only 1 record for Sec2? I've tried using distinct and unique but still get the same results.

Comment: Apologies I over simplified this initially. I actually need a date value from table B as well

Comment: Date value of which of the two records?

Comment: The record in tableB with the most recent date. Some of the records may not have a date value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT  secid, secname
FROM    tableA
WHERE   secid IN
        (
        SELECT  secid
        FROM    tableb
        )
```

If you need a record from `tableB` as well:

```
SELECT  secid, secname, datesent
FROM    (
        SELECT  a.secid, a.secname, b.datesent, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.secid ORDER BY b.datesent DESC) AS rn
        FROM   tableA a
        JOIN   tableB b
        ON     b.secid = a.secid
        )
WHERE   rn = 1
```

`ORDER BY` clause controls which of the multiple records on `b` will you get.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a GROUP function to select only one row:

```
SELECT A.SecID, A.SecName, max(B.DateSent) DateSent
  FROM tableA A   
  JOIN tableB B on A.SecID = B.SecID
 GROUP BY A.SecID, A.SecName
```

Comment: Hi @Vincent thanks - my full query has about 40 fields, so this means adding all fields except B.DateSent to the Group By clause, unless there's a different way.

Comment: If you have a lot of fields, Quassnoi's solution is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.secid, a.secname
  FROM tableA a, tableB b
 WHERE a.secid = b.secid;
```

Answer (score -1):

The solutions suggested are very good. There are cases when you may have take a bit different approach specially when one of the tables is very large compared to another one and absence of an index on foreign key column in table B.